# Two minor issues with the look of vote counts and vote icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I know I am being picky, but I realized two glitches in the vote count.  Both are minor, but anyway:

- The vote count appears lower than the center of the upvote icon and the downvote icon.  This may depend on which fonts are installed on a client system and I do not know if it can be solved for everyone.
- For an unknown reason, I noticed that the upvote icon and the downvote icon are not the mirror images of each other.  The downward arrow in the downvote icon looks one pixel or so too low.  (I verified that this was the case by enlarging a screenshot.)

I reproduced these behaviors with Firefox 3.6, IE 8 and Chrome 7.0 on Windows 7.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Memo: The first bullet is reported also in http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/712/new-design-launched/727#727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have adjusted the vertical alignment. You'll see the change in the next deployment. as for the second point, I initially had the down-vote icon as an exact mirror of the up-vote icon, but the arrow inside looked a bit weird, so I adjusted it by 1px.

Comment: +1 for the 1px part ;)

Comment: I verified the first point, and now I understand the second point is intentional.  Thanks for the fix and the explanation!